# display which value is higher between 2 column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

i have a table like this

```
╔═══════╦════════╗
║  VOL  ║ WEIGHT ║
╠═══════╬════════╣
║ 20.00 ║ 222.00 ║
╚═══════╩════════╝
```

but then i want to display which value is higher between 2 column
which is like...

```
╔═══════╦════════╦═════════╗
║  VOL  ║ WEIGHT ║ TONNAGE ║
╠═══════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ 20.00 ║ 222.00 ║ 222.00  ║
╚═══════╩════════╩═════════╝
```

Answer (score 5):

use `GREATEST`

```
SELECT vol, weight, GREATEST(vol, weight) Tonnage
FROM tableName
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a5444/1)

SOURCE

- [GREATEST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)

Comment: sorry for being thick. How is `Tonnage` thrown into the SQL statement? Is it the same thing as saying `GREATEST(vol, weight) as Tonnage`?

Comment: @SamuelCook yes, `AS` is an optional keyword to add an `ALIAS`, [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a5444/4)

Comment: Why isn't the "as" keyword needed? Is there any situation where it is actually needed?

Comment: @MatthewG not really needed but it's *optional*.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with previous post about `GREATEST`, but for a little more generic syntax, `CASE` works well too (should work with most RDBMS):

```
SELECT vol, 
  weight, 
  case 
     when vol > weight 
     then vol 
     else weight end as Tonnage
FROM tableName
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7ef28/1).